# получить параметры из строки запроса vk приложение

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Мне нужно получить токен пользователя при запуске приложения. В документации говорится:

```
При запуске приложения в строке запроса передаются дополнительные параметры,  
которые содержат в себе данные о пользователе и об источнике запуска.
```

Я пытаюсь получить строку с помощью **document.location.href** , но возвращается просто адрес, на котором находится приложение вида https://site.ru/index.php без каких-либо параметров.
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Неплохо было бы показать, что вы делаете (чем пользуетесь для авторизации, какой запрос шлете, чем, и пр), чтоб можно было сказать, что вы делаете не так.

Comment: у меня встроенное приложение iFrame, на странице только html-разметка (не вижу смысла ее кидать), при запуске приложения (как сказано в документации), в запросе передаются параметры (я так понял, типа alala.ru/index.php?par1=a&par2=b...) Но при получении строки запроса ничего нет. $_GET тоже, ессно, не работает. Мне это нужно для отправки запроса на php, т.к. на javascript нельзя отправить методом POST файл на сервер вк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти параметры являются частью query-строки. Например, указав в настройках приложения адрес `https://site.ru/index.php`, пользователь на самом деле попадет по примерно такому адресу (названия и количество GET-параметров могут меняться от типа приложения):

```
https://site.ru/index.php
?api_url=https://api.vk.com/api.php
&api_settings=0
&viewer_id=123456
&group_id=65432
&is_app_user=0
```

Соответственно, если вы внутри приложения сделаете редирект (например, с `https://site.ru/index.php` на `https://site.ru/`), перейдете по какой-нибудь ссылке или что-нибудь еще сделаете, то вы потеряете эти GET-параметры. Поэтому **отловить их вы можете только в момент запуска приложения до первого изменения адреса**, а там уже сами решайте, что с ними делать: помещать в кэш браузера или хранить где-нибудь на сервере.

Comment: это я вроде как понял, но попробовав сделать вызов для window.onload также получил просто адрес страницы без параметров. Затем попробовал событие VK.init (которое происходит еще до window.onload), и все равно то же самое

Comment: @Андрей, вы точно уверены, что при открытии вашего приложения в айфрейме не происходит никаких редиректов?

Comment: не должно. У меня сама страница голая, кроме стандартных тегов (head,body) там ничего нет. Только скрипт с выводом адреса. Выведенный адрес соответствует адресу IFrame в приложении. Я хз

Comment: Заработало!)) Просто у меня в Iframe указывалось без /index.php Дописал, теперь все приходит)))